# Having trouble installing wine on Debian 11

Tags: debian, wine

I'm trying to install wine and keep running into an issue where apt is telling me that I've held broken packages. I'm not super experienced with Linux, and I've already tried tons of different solutions I've seen elsewhere.

I've already added the repository by following the steps on the [WineHQ Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian), but every time I try to run `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`, I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.1~bullseye-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After seeing that, I decided to try and install `wine-stable` manually, but I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libasound2-plugins : Depends: libavcodec58 (>= 7:4.2)
 libasound2-plugins:i386 : Depends: libavcodec58:i386 (>= 7:4.2)
                           Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
                           Depends: libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (>= 1.9.10+20150825) but it is not installable or
                                    libjack-0.125:i386
                           Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1-1~) but it is not installable
 libavahi-client3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libavahi-common3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libavresample4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libavutil56:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libblkid1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libbrotli1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libbsd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 libbz2-1.0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libcairo2 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6) but it is not installable
             Depends: libxrender1 but it is not installable
 libcairo2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libcap2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.9) but it is not installable
 libcom-err2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 libcurl3-gnutls : Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not installable
 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libcurl4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libdb5.3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libsystemd0:i386
 libdeflate0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libdrm2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
 libdw1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.23) but it is not installable
 libelf1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libexif12:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libexpat1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 libffi7:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libfreetype6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libgcc-s1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not installable
 libgcrypt20:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libgd3 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6) but it is not installable
 libgd3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libgdbm-compat4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libgdbm6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libgmp10:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libgnutls30:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libgpg-error0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libgphoto2-port12:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but it is not installable
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
                                       Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 but it is not installable
 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libhogweed6 : Depends: libgmp10 (>= 2:6.1.0) but it is not installable
 libhogweed6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libicu67:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libidn2-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libieee1284-3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libjbig0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libjpeg62-turbo:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libk5crypto3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libkeyutils1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libkrb5-3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libkrb5support0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not installable
 liblcms2-2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libldap-2.4-2 : Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0) but it is not installable
 libldap-2.4-2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libltdl7:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 liblzma5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
 libmd0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libmount1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libnettle8:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libnghttp2-14:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libnsl2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libnspr4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.30) but it is not installable
 libnss3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libopenal1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.27) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not installable
 libopenjp2-7:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 liborc-0.4-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libp11-kit0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libpci3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libpcre2-8-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libpcre3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libperl5.32:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libpixman-1-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libpng16-16:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libpoppler-glib8:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libpoppler102 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.12.6) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.16) but it is not installable
 libpoppler102:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libpsl5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 librtmp1 : Depends: libgmp10 but it is not installable
            Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.14) but it is not installable
 librtmp1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libsamplerate0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libsane1 : Depends: libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16) but it is not installable
            Depends: libavahi-common3 (>= 0.6.16) but it is not installable
            Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.31-4.1)
            Recommends: ipp-usb
 libsane1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sane-utils:i386 (>= 1.0.31-4.1)
                 Recommends: ipp-usb:i386
 libsasl2-2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
                   Recommends: libsasl2-modules:i386 (>= 2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1) but it is not installable
 libsasl2-modules-db:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libselinux1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libsensors5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libsndio7.0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.16) but it is not installable
 libsnmp40:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libsqlite3-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libssh2-1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libssl1.1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libstdc++6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.23) but it is not installable
 libtasn1-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libtiff5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libtirpc3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libudev1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.30) but it is not installable
 libunistring2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libunwind8:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not installable
 libusb-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libuuid1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libva-drm2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libva-x11-2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.1.3) but it is not installable
 libva2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
               Recommends: va-driver-all:i386 but it is not installable or
                           va-driver:i386
 libvdpau1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: vdpau-driver-all:i386 but it is not installable or
                              vdpau-driver:i386
 libwebp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libwrap0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not installable
 libx11-6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libxau6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxcb-render0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxcb-shm0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
 libxdmcp6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxext6:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxfixes3:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libxml2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
 libxpm4:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libxrender1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 libzstd1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
 ucf : Depends: coreutils (>= 5.91)
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.29) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libncurses6:i386 but it is not installable or
                                  libncurses5:i386 but it is not installable or
                                  libncurses:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not installable or
                                     libglu1:i386
                         Recommends: libgsm1:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libodbc1:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libxcomposite1:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libxcursor1:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libxi6:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 but it is not installable
                         Recommends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not installable
 zlib1g:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After that, I looked up some solutions and saw someone suggest using `aptitude` since it can help solve issues, so I installed it and tried to install `winehq-stable` using it and got this:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  winehq-stable{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,924 B of archives. After unpacking 74.8 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.1~bullseye-1) but it is not installable
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     winehq-stable [Not Installed]                      



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

Obviously I don't accept this solution because I'd like to install Wine, so I entered `n` and got this:

(Character limit, hastebin link: https://hst.sh/comobabugi.yaml)

Now, I'm no Linux expert as I said above, but some of these packages that it wants to remove may be important, which is what I'm wondering - would this solve my problem with installing Wine and is it safe to accept this solution?

Please note: I also run Pi-hole (with web interface) and a Wireguard Server.

Comment: You need to enable 32bit repositories.

Comment: @mashuptwice I've already done what the WineHQ Wiki says, if that's what you meant. (`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`)

Comment: followed by a `sudo apt update` to refresh the package list? Apart from that: do you have any specific reason to use `winehq` instead of `wine`?

Comment: @mashuptwice yeah, I refreshed the package list as well. As I mentioned in the post, I tried installing `wine-stable` as well, but got a long list of 32-bit dependencies that could not be installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic, but since you have broken packages did you try already?

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

That should try to fix the broken packages, until you solve that, apt will not allow you to continue(at least safely)

If you had try it then. Which package are broken?